# Unchecked cast abstract base class

Tags: java, casting, abstract-class

Can someone explain me, why this cast is unchecked. It should be guaranteed that type `T` is always derived from `Base` and so the cast from `T` to `Base` should not be unchecked.

```
abstract class Base
{
    private static final Map<Class<? extends Base>, Consumer<Base>> _CONSUMERS = new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    public static <T extends Base> void addConsumer( Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> consumer )
    {
        _CONSUMERS.put( clazz, (Consumer<Base>) consumer );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `consumer` is `Consumer<T>` = `Consumer<? extends Base>`, while the `put` expects a `Consumer<Base>`.

You should probably declare your `_CONSUMERS` map as of type:

```
Map<Class<? extends Base>, Consumer<? extends Base>>
```

Java does not recognize situations where objects of type `X<? extends T>` (or `X<? super T>`) can be used in place of `X<T>`, you have to explicitly indicate type bounds (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p/2745301#2745301) a more thorough discussion about this).

Comment: I adopted your answer, and now the the put has no more warnings, but when I want to call the consumer, I have to do an unchecked cast `Consumer<Base> consumer = (Consumer<Base>) _CONSUMERS.get( Concrete.class );`. Otherwise I can not call `accept`.

Comment: I forgot... if you are dealing with a `java.util.function.Consumer` (or something similar in concept), I think you should use `<? super Base>` in place of than `<? extends Base>`: this should let you retrieve a `Consumer<? super Base>` and call its `accept` method with a `Base`-typed argument without any casting

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, but I was incapable of solving the problem with `super` and without a suppression of warnings.